# Where should I save created files?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to save users created pdf files somewhere. I wanted to save files to ClassPathResource (but I read that It is not a good idea), because I need one thing... Application must work on every computer... so I cannot save it directly on my disc...
Any recommendation, where I could save pdf files to make it work as I need?

Comment: Save it to a cloud server ? Or an "object storage service"

Comment: how about temp folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to save it in the user home directory. `System.getProperty(„user.home“)`. This works on Linux and on Windows.